# Where are 'wine' program execution logs stored?

Tags: wine

Or how I can start *.exe with wine in console?
Run with wine menu item gives such result:

```
nothing happens and no errors.
```

Comment: Open a Terminal where the Windows executable .exe file is and type "wine program_name.exe". You will see the Wine log in Terminal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The wine run logs are hidden typically, they're not stored anywhere.

To get the Wine logs for a specific executable, you need to run it via the terminal with the `wine` command.

```
wine /path/to/program.exe
```

Note you need the full path here, or you need to first `cd` into the directory where the .exe is stored.

Answer (score 4):

If you need error logs for an application that crashes with a graphics anomaly that leaves you unable to view the terminal output (as happened to me) simply redirect the output to a file that you can examine later as I did.

`wine /path/to/program.exe > wine.error.log`

**Edit:**

If you want a log created every time you launch a program with wine `alias` can help you do this.

`alias wine='wine 2>wine.error.log'` will create a log in the directory where the executable is stored every time. The `2` specifies that *stderr* will be redirected to the log file specified. If for some reason you want to store this file where your other logs are kept (not recommended) you can adjust the output path accordingly as in  `alias wine='wine 2>/var/log/wine.error.log` If you want to locate all the wine error logs so that you can review them `find` is useful for this:

`find $HOME -iname *.error.log 2>/dev/null`

This launches `find` starting in your home directory. the `-iname` switch tells it to ignore case (you could use `-name` instead which matches case but force of habit on my part) `*.error.log` is the filename we are looking for (you could use `wine.error.log` instead but I don't want to type that much.) And finally here `>2/dev/null` is redirecting *stderr* to the bit bucket (`/dev/null`) so that we ignore any "Permission denied" output we may have otherwise received.

**Note:** I have not tested this in scenarios where wine is launched with parameters other than just the program to be launched.

Comment: the command `wine /path/to/program.exe > wine.error.log` didn't redirect the output for me. instead, it kept printing on the terminal, keeping the target file empty.

Comment: @MerajalMaksud feel free to share your solution or ask another question. Reference this answer to provide context if you feel that will help with your specific situation.