How to find out the cause of an Desktop Crash?
I've got the following system:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
KERNEL: 6.5.0-28-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800X3D 8-Core
GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT (navi23, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.54,
6.5.0-28-generic)
GPU DRIVER: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
RAM: 16 GB

Now the problem is that previously, while Steam was somewhat unstable at times (still unsure why) and did cause freezes for Ubuntu, I didn't have so far hard crashes except the first few times I tried Cyberpunk on Linux (and got shit performance on the game through Steam Proton, including crashes) months ago after the release of Cyberpunk 2077 2.1.
However today Cyberpunk 2077: Phantom Liberty caused a hard crash on me. Or more specifically, a Desktop Crash (I got forcibly logged out after some time). Currently I've got Xorg set instead of Wayland, if that does matter.
Previously I had memory overflow issues on Windows with Cyberpunk 2077 (with the launcher part which caused no end of overflows), but I thought that on Linux no longer mattered because the typical signals of the memory overflow I had on Windows didn't pop up on my Ubuntu install (freezing of the game with resumption of operations half a minute later).
Now I want to find out what caused the issue (e.g. memory overflow or something else), but the previous answers related to desktop crashes or anything system crashes aren't helping me to find the relevant logs. Can someone please give me a pointer? Would appreciate it.
I've tried to find a Xorg log in /var/log (very old answer) but didn't exist, I tried /var/crash but the log there doesn't have the desktop crash of today....

https://askubuntu.com/questions/707941/where-are-wine-program-execution-logs-stored  to enable and log from wine. Use that, wait for a crash and analyze the log. what you list now had nothing to go on :)
